# What's the difference between these studs?

Tags: flash-bracket, lightstands

I have [this bracket](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00JAAXH1A) and I'm trying to put it on two different light stands. The stud on this one fits perfectly:[image: Fits] (it's a [Westcott 9910 stand](https://www.fjwestcott.com/10-light-stand-heavy-duty)). The socket slides all the way down on the stud so when the screw is tightened it is straight and very secure. Here's a picture of it fitting: [image]

However, the stud on this one seems about the same, but basically doesn't fit: [image: Does not fit] (it's [this Impact LS_CS40M-40 stand](https://www.impactstudiolighting.com/product/5078/Impact-LS_CS40M-40''-C_Stand-with-Sliding-Leg-(Chrome_plated,-11'))). The socket slides most of the way down, but it doesn't "seat" at the bottom, so when I tighten the screw it lean sideways and doesn't seem at all secure. Here is a picture of the "lean" that is induced:
[image]
and a clear explanation of the problem - that the bracket is not reaching the larger diameter part of the stud at the bottom: [image]

Do these studs have different names? Is there an adapter I can get for the one that doesn't fit to make it fit the bracket? Or should I get a different bracket to match the stud directly?

EDIT---
Here's a side-by-side:
[image]

Comment: The studs are removable. Why not replace the stud with one that fits your bracket better?

Comment: @MikeSowsun Really? I tried pulling and twisting but they didn't seem to budge.

Comment: @MikeSowsun Done. I also posted links to the stands. The Westcott doesn't say anything about the stud at all. The Impact says it's a 5/8" stud, but doesn't list the length. Isn't this a critical dimension? (The bracket product description also oddly doesn't list the length of the socket).

Answer (score 2):

They're both "baby" studs/spuds/pins... up to a point. Notice that the one with the 1/4-20 threaded top section is about the same overall length, but that the 1/4-20 threaded section is *just a touch* skinnier than the 5/8" body below it.

A normal baby socket is *at least* 1 3/16" (30mm) deep. The socket on your flash bracket is that deep - your 1/4"-20-topped stud wouldn't fit all the way if it weren't - but it's not 5/8" in diameter for all of that depth. The 1/4"-20 bit at the top can go places where the flap-topped pin on the C-stand can't go. (You would probably find the same bad fit if you put the standard plastic thread protector over the 1/4"-20 thread on that stud.)

So the problem is the flash bracket. Don't get too upset about that - it's both good enough for "normal" use (most light stands in use aren't "proper" grip equipment; they're lightweight "location" stands with the sort of studs your smaller stand has, including a 1/4"-20 threaded section or reversible 1/4"-20 and 3/8"-16 sections) and cheaper to manufacture and to purchase with the socket it has. The socket can be fixed in a couple of seconds with a drill bit that can flatten the bottom of the socket - a brad point drill should do the trick. And any "pro" lighting equipment will already have a socket that's shaped properly for a standard baby pin, since they're more likely to be regularly used on C-stands, plates, grip arms, and so forth.

Oh, and the extra length below the reduced area? That's to allow you to attach grip heads and so on - they need a much longer 5/8" pin than a light's socket does.

Comment: so are there simply not S-brackets that will fit "correctly" on the silver stand? Or a stud adapter to make the silver stand stud into the black stand stud?

Answer (score 0):

The larger diameter stud is the light stand standard 5/8 inch version.

The smaller stud is the 3/8 inch version.

https://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/search?Ntt=5%2F8%20inch%20stud

These are not replacements, instead they are adapters for some mounting brakets.

The 3/8 should technically work if your flash socket is deep enough to reach the lower larger diameter to hold it straight.

Comment: Are these measurements talking about length or diameter? They seem to be the same diameter.

Comment: 5/8 inch is the diameter (the larger diameter of the hole in the light, but there is recessed length where the screw tightens, which can become nicked and rough, esp if brass).   I couldn't judge diameter of the bottom one, it looked smaller.   The top one is very standard.

Comment: I added a side by side picture and a link to the stands.

Comment: Then they ought to work alike.  If the light is leaning, it must not be seating deep enough to reach the bottom larger diameter to hold it straight.  Leaning shouldn't really matter, you can always aim it as needed. Tighten the screw to hold it secure.

Comment: I added pictures of the bracket attached to both stands. You're clearly correct that the bracket isn't reaching the bottom larger diameter of the stud. I'm not worried about aiming the light, but more that the screw shouldn't be taking the weight as it is, but rather just be a failsafe for the bracket to not detach from the stud. In the product description of the bracket I don't see anything about a "length of the stud socket" - isn't that a critical dimension that they should list and I should be looking for?

Comment: I don't know why the one stand needs a deeper light socket (make sure the socket is clear and not blocked by something),  but it should still work OK if tilted a bit. If the screw is not fully tight, the light might swivel its aim, but the larger diameter at the stand top will still prevent it from falling off.

Comment: Yea, does it "work"? Sure. But it's certainly not "right" haha. I guess what I'm looking for is which one is more "standard"? Like if I want it "right", should I buy a different bracket to match the deeper stud? Or should I buy a stud converter to match the shallower bracket?

Comment: Don't know, but one obvious solution is to use the bracket on the stand that fits it.  That top stand is a very standard mount.